# Причины возникновения ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE при загрузке страниц

Tags: php, сервер, apache2

Есть сайт, который работает под apache2. Периодически, при загрузке страницы возникает ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, при этом, страница загружается нормально меньше, чем через секунду. Вот, что выдает /var/log/apache2/error.log:

> [Fri Jun 22 13:02:46.095370 2018] [mpm_itk:error] [pid 28426] child died with signal

Такие записи там появляются примерно 10 раз в час. Погуглив, я нашел похожую проблему по этой ссылке:

> https://danfa.net/forum/thread/1465/

Там в кач-ве решения предлагают увеличить объем оперативной памяти, однако, на VDS используется только 1 из 12 гб, т.е. объема более, чем достаточно.

Конфигурационный файл mpm_itk:

> LimitUIDRange 0 65000
>   LimitGIDRange 0 65000

Вопрос: как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Ваш VDS у какого-то хостера, так? Напишите в поддержку, пусть разбираются.